# Too X, X enough, enough X

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain why the choices not marked as 'correct' in these fill-in-the-blank questions are wrong?

**It was *_*__ so we didn't get it.**
expensive enough
too expensive -correct
enough expensive

**It's *_*____ to read; I don't understand it at all.**
enough difficult
too difficult -correct
difficult enough

**It's not *_*____ to sort things out.**
enough late
late enough
too late -correct

**It's *_*____ to pass.**
enough difficult
too difficult -correct
difficult enough

**It's *_*____ walk—I'll take the bus.**
enough far
far enough
too far -correct
too much far

Are 'much enough' ever used together? For example,

**He ate *_*____ and felt ill.**
enough much
much enough
too much

Comment: "It's difficult enough to pass." could be fine, depending on context (and I have no idea what context would be implied in an ESL exercise). *"It's difficult enough to pass. I'm not even going to try it with a boat trailer on my car."* — although I believe British English uses *overtake* rather than *pass*.

Comment: 3 more votes needed to close this question? Please, don't vote against this question. I need those explanations badly.

Comment: Monica, you must add two spaces at the end of your lines to force a new line.

Comment: Does anybody **ever** use *enough difficult*?

Comment: Closed as too localized? That's the worst site for English help indeed.

Comment: Very briefly, since we're closed: *Too [Adj] to [Verb]* is equivalent to "So [Adj] that one **cannot** [Verb]". *[Adj] enough to [Verb]* is equivalent to "So [Adj] that one **can** [Verb]". *Enough* is used **before** nouns, **after** adjectives.  And  *enough* is never used with *much*; in the prohibitive construction one says "too much to" and in the permissive construction simply "enough to".

Comment: @Monica, you haven't done your research if you think ELU is “the worst site for English help indeed”.  I think [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) and [Unpedia](http://un-pedia.wikia.com/wiki/Unpedia_Wiki) are far worse.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  A good answer to this question would provide good general rules for using "too" and "enough" - common words that learners of English often use incorrectly.  There is just NO WAY this question can be considered too localised.

Comment: @DavidWallace If this site helps an English learner, great, but it exists primarily to serve experts. A question which is too basic is subject to being closed and eventually deleted. In practice it often depends on whether an interesting answer presents itself.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: I agree – and I think the interesting answer you allude to may have presented itself. (I wouldn't consider myself an "English learner," but I found David's answer enlightening nonetheless.) It's one thing to know how to use the word _enough_, but it's a bit of a challenge to explain it in a generic way. I'd consider myself more of an expert than a novice, but I was edified by David's eloquent answer. Therefore, I'd now argue that the question has merit.

Comment: @StoneyB, I'll +1 if you make answer of comment

Comment: @jwpat7  Very gracious of you, but I think David Wallace has already said all I had to say, with more examples. (But I am quite proud of getting that much into so small a compass!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key point here is that if something is "too expensive", "too difficult", "too late" or whatever, then this **prevents** you from doing what you otherwise would.

- The car was too expensive, so I didn't buy it.
- The problem was too difficult, so I couldn't solve it.
- The party started too late, so I didn't attend.

In a sense, "enough" works the opposite way.  That is, if something is "cheap enough", "easy enough", "early enough", then this **enables** you to do something.

- The car was cheap enough, so I bought it.
- The question was easy enough, so I posted an answer.
- The party started early enough, so I went along and stayed for a while.

Note also that when "enough" is an adverb, it follows the adjective or verb that it qualifies.  When it is used as an adjective, it usually precedes the noun.

- The car had enough petrol in the tank.
- The question had enough merit to warrant being re-opened.

Comment: I'm glad this question got reopened; this is an excellent answer. (I'll leave mine there, but, if no one else answers, I think Monica should choose yours.)

Comment: I am very grateful to those who voted for my question to be reopened.

Comment: So 'enough' either enables  you to do something or prevents you from doing something(as in this example; We didn't go out to dinner after the show; the tickets to the play were expensive enough.), but I don't see how 'far enough' means  that 'it is not too far, I can walk'.

Comment: @Monica: "It is not too far, I can walk" would be conveyed with _close enough_, not _far enough_, as in, "The theater is close enough, we can walk."

Answer (score 3):

For many of these questions, the idea is that the word *enough* is not used in the same way as *too* or *very* are used; you simply don't say *enough difficult*, or *enough expensive*.  When modifying an adjective, the word is *enough* is used *after* the word it modifies, not before:

> He's old enough to stay out past midnight.
>   He's skilled enough to ski down the expert trail.

If you want to use a word before the adjective, you can use *sufficiently*:

> He's sufficiently skilled to ski down the expert trail.

or, you can restructure the sentence, and use *enough* to modify a noun:

> He has enough skill to ski down the expert trail.

---

As for this example problem:

> It was `______` so we didn't get it.
>    a. expensive enough
>    b. too expensive - *correct*
>    c. enough expensive

As I mentioned previously, I can't think of an instance when I would *ever* say "enough expensive." As for "expensive enough", there are times I might use that wording, but *not* within the "It was `___`, so..." construct.  However, I might say:

> We didn't go out to dinner after the show; the tickets to the play were expensive enough.

As for this one:

> It's `_____` to read; I don't understand it at all.
>   a. enough difficult
>   b. too difficult - *correct*
>   c. difficult enough

Again, (a) is just downright awkward.  The third option almost works, but *too difficult* matches better with the speaker not understanding the reading material.  If, however, the sentence had said,

> It's `_____` to read; I think it'll take me forever to finish that book!

then (c) might be more acceptable, because the word *enough* can be used for emphasis, where "difficult enough" can mean, essentially, "very difficult."

---

As for this one:

> It's not `_____` to sort things out.
>   a. late enough
>   b. too late - *correct*

There's nothing wrong with saying *late enough*, but not in this context (because it's hard to think of a context where it's too early to sort things out).  Instead, one might say:

> It's not late enough in the day yet to start selling our bread for half price.

(Admittedly, I'd probably opt for "too early," instead of "not late enough," but, nevertheless, that sentence is grammatical.)

---

I hope these explanations help you out.  It's hard to tackle all six of these at once – which is why some may have voted to close the question initially.  Hopefully, though, I've explained enough, so that you can figure out the ones I didn't address.

One last thought, about your comment (that this must be "the worst site for English help"): to that, I say, "*Enough, already*."  I think there are enough helpful people on EL&U that such comments are unwarranted and unnecessary.

Comment: +1, I might add that in the"*expensive enough/too expensive*" question, it is the use of *so* that breaks *expensive enough*- changing *so* to *that* would result in, "*It was expensive enough that we didn't get it*" which reads okay in my book.